# read.table() read numeric valuse as integer in R

Tags: r, numeric, read.table

I am using `Data <- read.table("file", head=TRUE, sep=";")` to read my file.

The `head` of my file looks like this:

```
         Date     Time Global_active_power Global_reactive_power Voltage Global_intensity
66637 2007-02-01 00:00:00               0.326                 0.128 243.150            1.400
66638 2007-02-01 00:01:00               0.326                 0.130 243.320            1.400
66639 2007-02-01 00:02:00               0.324                 0.132 243.510            1.400
66640 2007-02-01 00:03:00               0.324                 0.134 243.900            1.400
66641 2007-02-01 00:04:00               0.322                 0.130 243.160            1.400
66642 2007-02-01 00:05:00               0.320                 0.126 242.290            1.400
      Sub_metering_1 Sub_metering_2 Sub_metering_3
66637          0.000          0.000              0
66638          0.000          0.000              0
66639          0.000          0.000              0
66640          0.000          0.000              0
66641          0.000          0.000              0
66642          0.000          0.000              0
```

However, if I try `typeof(Data$Global_reactive_power)` it shows `integer` (should be `numeric`).

I do not understand why it is happening. I tried many methods but somehow none of them works, can any one help me for this?

My file is here:
https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/exdata%2Fdata%2Fhousehold_power_consumption.zip

Comment: You can read in your data as you did above and use `Data$Global_reactive_power <- as.numeric(Data$Global_reactive_power)` after, or you can manually specify the class of each column in your call to `read.table`. See the `colClasses` argument in the help file for `read.table` (`?read.table`).

Comment: I tried as.numeric(Data$Global_reactive_power), however, it will try the data to be integer (attribution is double though.) the first line will be 
            Date     Time Global_active_power Global_reactive_power Voltage Global_intensity
66637 2007-02-01 00:00:00                 126                    43 243.150            1.400

Comment: it changes the value of 0.326 to be 126 and so on.

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of your file (first few lines) so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I added the link of my file.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that your raw data as "?" for missing values. I looked by using

```
is.not.numeric<-function(x) {
    is.na(as.numeric(as.character(x)))
}

head(Filter(is.not.numeric, Data$Global_reactive_power))
```

When R encounters a non-numeric value such as "?" in a column, it coerces the column to a factor. In order you read your data in correctly, try

```
Data<-read.table("household_power_consumption.txt", 
    header=TRUE, sep=";", na.strings="?")
```

Now

```
class(Data$Global_reactive_power)
# [1] "numeric"
```

shows that it's numeric. (Note that you should never really need to use `typeof`. That tells you how the data for an object is stored, it doesn't tell you what the object *is*. Use `class()` for that).

Answer (score 3):

Your `Global_reactive_power` column has some non-numeric entries in it, which is causing `read.table` to turn it into a factor. Note that `typeof(factor)` is `integer`.

Open your file in a text editor and look for entries that aren't strictly numeric. If your data came from Excel, be sure to remove all formatting from columns (other than dates) before exporting to text.

Comment: or try `which(is.na(as.numeric(as.character(d$Global_reactive_power))))` to locate the problems

Comment: I tried 'which(is.na(as.numeric(as.character(d$Global_reactive_power))))', it produced a vector full of FALSE.

Comment: @Ginger The `which()` command should never return logical values, it should return indexes (integers). Are you sure you ran that line of code correctly?